# Seemingly random decoding errors

Tags: python, scripting, import

I'm working on an import export addon, and while importing a skeleton I'm running into a wide variety of errors when importing the .skl skeleton file. They all point to the same place in my script though.

```
class sklHeader():
    """SKL header format:
    fileType       char[8]    8    version string
    numObjects     int        4    number of objects (skeletons)
    skeltonHash    int        4    unique id numbers
    numElements    int        4    number of bones

    total size                20 bytes
    """

    def __init__(self):
        self.__format__ = '<8s3i'
        self.__size__ = struct.calsize(self.__format__)
        self.fileType = None
        self.numObjects = None
        self.skeltonHash = None
        self.numElements = None

    def fromFile(self, sklFile):
        """Reads the skl header object from the raw binary file"""
        sklFile.seek(0)
        fields = struct.unpack(self.__format__, sklFile.read(self.__size__))
        (fileType, self.numObjects, self.skeletonHash, self.numElements) = fields
        self.fileType = bytes.decode(fileType)
        #self.fileType = fileType

    def toFile(self, sklFile):
        """"Writes the header object to a raw binary file"""
        data = struct.pack(self.__format__, self.fileType, self.numObjects, self.skeletonHash, self.numElements)
        sklFile.write(data)
```

specifically all the errors are pointing to the same line

```
self.fileType = bytes.decode(fileType)
```

but I am getting a wide variety of errors most of them are invalid continuation bytes or invalid start bytes.

```
UnicodeDecodeError: utf-8 codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 4
UnicodeDecodeError: utf-8 codec can't decode byte 0xd5 in position 2

UnicodeDecodeError: utf-8 codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 0
UnicodeDecodeError: utf-8 codec can't decode byte 0xc8 in position 0
UnicodeDecodeError: utf-8 codec can't decode byte 0xb8 in position 0
UnicodeDecodeError: utf-8 codec can't decode byte 0xa4 in position 0
UnicodeDecodeError: utf-8 codec can't decode byte 0xa8 in position 0
```

All the ones in position 0 are invalid start bytes
the others are invalid continuation bytes.

Sometimes it works fine, other times I get errors such as these.

Any ideas?

> The .py file this is in, is what actually opens the .skl file its another 200+ lines defining how to use the raw data
>
> Skl files have to be unicode or it wouldn't sometimes work correctly.

Comment: What code do you use to open the file? Do SKL files even contain unicode characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Skl files have to be unicode or it wouldn't sometimes work correctly.

That's a really vague statement. I'm pretty convinced they are binary files, which may or may not contain some unicode-encoded strings. But you definitely need to open them as binary files:

```
file = open(filepath, "rb")
```

You may then decode binary strings:

```
binary_object.decode("utf-8")
```

Reading the file in binary mode will prevent decoding errors caused by non-strings (which can be a simple `'\x89'` of a binary integer.

Comment: so the binary_object.decode() would replace my current decoder or is that something that has to be tied to the open(filepath)?

Comment: `open(...)` needs to have the binary flag set, or it will return strings. The decoding of binary objects is not directly related, `str.encode()` and `bytes.decode()` are generic methods of the both built-in types str and bytes.